# Can't access WP-Admin page because of error

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to edit a website I made in Wordpress, but when I go to the `example.com/wp-admin/`  to get to the Admin,

I get the **errors**, and so there is no way to go into Wordpress to edit the site.
I even changed the WP Theme back to the default **TwentyTen** through **PHPMyAdmin**, but that didn't help.

What can I do? Here is what I get when I try to go to wp-admin page:

> Notice: register_uninstall_hook was called incorrectly. Only a static
> class method or function can be used in an uninstall hook. Please see
> Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
> in version 3.1.) in
> /home/content/80/13163980/html/ybk/wp-includes/functions.php on line
> 3547
>
> Notice: Undefined index: page in
> /home/content/80/13163980/html/ybk/wp-content/themes/rt_infuse_wp/functions.php
> on line 45
>
> Notice: Undefined index: page in
> /home/content/80/13163980/html/ybk/wp-content/themes/rt_infuse_wp/functions.php
> on line 55
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/content/80/13163980/html/ybk/wp-includes/functions.php:3547) in
> /home/content/80/13163980/html/ybk/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line
> 1178

Answer (score 1):

I just set WP_DEBUG mode to false and that skipped it all and got me to the WP-Admin login page.

Answer (score 1):

Just find the `pluggable.php` and after `<?php` please add this `ob_start();` and save. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Removing "blank lines" from **function.php** file and check it now issue is as it is than after check plugin folder >> disable plugin and check

Refresh your Browser, and the original error message *Should* go away.

Comment: Thanks. Before I saw your post I just set WP_DEBUG mode to false and that skipped it all and got me to the WP-Admin login page.